# How tight is this trace inequality?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, inequality, trace

I would like to know how tight the following trace inequalities are for real symmetric $A$ and real symmetric $B \succeq 0$

$$\mbox{trace} (AB) \leq \lambda_{\max} (A) \cdot \mbox{trace} (B) $$

or 
$$\mbox{trace} (BA) \leq \lambda_{\max} (B) \cdot \mbox{trace} (A) $$

since it is said below eq (1) of

> https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Qingling_Zhang4/publication/3032531_Eigenvalue_Inequalities_for_Matrix_Product/links/0c96052cc720dc4b9d000000.pdf

the second line holds. I tried to run some simulations (for various $A,B$ obeying the above), but there seems to be a big difference between the two upper bounds and the upper bounds are pretty far away from $\mbox{trace} (AB)$. Any theoretical insights on the tightness of this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are tight, in the sense that we have $\text{trace}(AB) = \lambda_{max}(A)\; \text{trace}(B)$ if $A = I$.
Similarly in the second one if $B=I$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I have that $B \succeq 0$, but I am not sure about the definiteness of $A$, then, can anything be said about which of the inequalities I can use to get a tighter result or not really? (In my problem I have the flexibility to design $A$ and I want $trace(AB) \leq 0$, but I would like to operate on either $trace(A)$ or $\lambda_{max} (A)$). Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I was wondering if you could kindly help me with this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887554/find-2-norm-conditions-on-a-matrix-to-make-the-following-true
I would like to find conditions on $A$ that would make the inequality true. Any advice would be appreciated. thanks.